# With serverless framework, how to replace cognito user pool instead of update?

Tags: serverless-framework

I am using serverless framework to manage my AWS resources. Now I want to replace my cognito user pool to update the config of alias, username attributes, etc.

I have:
- changed the config of cognito user pool resource in .yml
- changed the cognito user pool name and client name

But on deploy, I got the error:
`Updates are not allowed for property - UserPoolName.`

where I was expected that this should lead to an replacement, not update.

What have I missed?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bit of a hack/work around, but you can remove the `cognito user pool` from your `serverless.yml`. Deploy to AWS - this will remove the pool. Then add the details back into `serverless.yml` including the changes you need, then deploy to aws.

Comment: Yes I figured that out as well. Thanks~

Comment: Can you elaborate more on 'remove `cognito user pool`'? Do you mean `amplify auth remove` or just editing out the configurations in the CloudFormation template?

Comment: @DevYego "remove the cognito user pool from your serverless.yml" so yes, remove from CloudFormation

Comment: Oh, that won't be pretty for my case. The user pool is a dependency on other resources of the app that I don't want to touch.

Comment: @DevYego then you sir, have a tightly coupled architecture. Prepare for more problems like this - often.

Comment: Haha, I know. But it's the only option I had when working with Amplify.

Comment: @DevYego Ideally you should have created a 'User Service'. Cognito lives in there, and the only resources that depend directly on cognito live in your users service. Other service will presumably use cognito for authenication. This is easily done through a custom authorizor on API Gateway that makes an api call to the congnito user group. This is loosely coupled as you only need to know the user group name, you arent coupling resources together at the cloudformation level